# flink how to get exceptionHistory inside the program?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I know I can call `http://<host>:<port>/jobs/<jobId>/exceptions` to get exception history of my flink job. Is there anyway I can do inside my flink program to get this instead of sending request externally? I just wonder what does flink do when I send this request?

I've tried to start a scheduler when my flink job starts and send GET request periodically. But I'm using `flink run-application -t yarn-application <myJar>` to run my program in application-mode, each time host and port are different. So I guess if I can get host and port inside my program, I can create this scheduler

Comment: Flink isn't really set up to make this pattern easy to implement -- i.e., where a job observes its own behavior, and somehow reacts to that. You might consider instead using something outside of Flink to observe and control the job.